# IRIS alternative on mac?

Tags: astronomy, software, astrometrics

I need to process some images taken from a telescope to determine the intensity of an astroid. 
This way I can determine the rotation period of this asteroid.

The pictures were taken the usual way (I guess, I'm not an astronomer, this is a school project), setting the telescope to track a nearby star. I would need to do dark frame and flat field correction on a lot of images (so batch processing would be great). Since the asteroid is moving in relation to the star, there would also have to be functionality to bring this into account.

Is there a piece of software (**for mac**) around that can do this? I know Iris exist for windows, but I don't have a PC with windows available, and learning a new piece of software on a computer that isn't mine (eg in the library) will only lead to frustration.

Comment: have you considered installing windows in a virtualbox image?

Comment: You can check the list here to see if one of the [alternatives](http://www.zerobyzero.ca/Starstruck/?page_id=248) can do what you want.

Comment: yes, virtualbox does the job.. answer it and I'll commit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- install virtualbox in your mac
- create a windows image
- install IRIS on your windows image
- work as usual

Comment: haha, ab bit late, but hey.. if it works it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try using WineBottler: http://winebottler.kronenberg.org

I have not used IRIS with it to it's full extent, but you can try it out and see if doesn't change the processes.